# Solving a puzzle in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I tried to solve this puzzle https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40094/who-committed-the-crime using Racket.

> A crime has been carried out by one person, there are 5 suspects. Each
>   suspect is asked under polygraph who they think committed the crime.
>
> Their answers are as follows:

```
Terry : It wasn't Carl, It was Steve 
Steve : It wasn't Matt, It wasn't Carl 
Matt : It was Carl, It wasn't Terry 
Ben : It was Matt, It was Steve 
Carl : It was Ben, It wasn't Terry
```

> The polygraph showed that
>   each suspect told one lie and one truth. Who committed the crime?

Following is my code:

```
(define (oneof a b)
  (or (and a (not b)) (and b (not a))))

(for ((i 5))
  (define templist (list #f #f #f #f #f))  ; make a temporary list of all false; 
  (set! templist (list-set templist i #t)) ; one by one keep one as true in this loop; 
  (define t (list-ref templist 0))   ; allocate each person according to above list (one kept true one by one)
  (define s (list-ref templist 1))
  (define m (list-ref templist 2))
  (define b (list-ref templist 3))
  (define c (list-ref templist 4))

  (when                              ; test if all statements fit with above assignment: 
    (and
     (oneof  (not c) s)              ; Terry's statement
     (oneof  (not m) (not c))        ; Steve's statement
     (oneof  c (not t))              ; Matt's statement
     (oneof  m s)                    ; Ben's statement
     (oneof  b (not t)))             ; Carl's statement
    (println (list "t" "s" "m" "b" "c"))  ; print allocation if all statement fit in; 
    (println templist)))
```

Output indicates Matt committed the crime:

```
'("t" "s" "m" "b" "c")
'(#f #f #t #f #f)
```

It works but the code is imperative and not very functional (especially define t, define s, ... part). How can it can be improved? Thanks for your comments/answers.

Comment: Code review SO would be a better fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an equivalent program written in idiomatic Racket - and avoiding all those pesky `set!` and `list-ref` which are frowned upon when writing functional-style code:

```
; generate a matrix with possibilities
(define (make-matrix n)
  (for/list [(i (in-range n))]
    (build-list n (λ (j) (= i j)))))

; iterate over each row
(for [(row (make-matrix 5))]
  ; unpack each row into the corresponding variables
  (match-let ([(list t s m b c) row])
    ; don't reinvent the wheel, `oneof` is called `xor`
    (when (and (xor (not c) s)
               (xor (not m) (not c))
               (xor c (not t))
               (xor m s)
               (xor b (not t)))
      (println '(t s m b c))
      (println row))))
```

Comment: Many new functions in here for me!

Comment: Study the documentation, you'll find that everything you're used to in imperative code has a nicer, leaner equivalent in functional code

Comment: An even more idiomatic solution would use `for/list` instead of `for`, `cond` instead of `when`, returning `row` instead of printing it, and returning false if the conditions weren't satisfied, so that a `(filter identity ...)` around the whole thing returns all the valid possibilities.

Comment: @AlexKnauth : It will be clearer if you entered that as an answer.

Comment: See http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37327/telling-the-truth/40242#40242 also.

Comment: Okay. I ended up using a simple `filter` instead of a `for/list`, `cond`, and `filter` together.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is based on @Oscar Lopez's answer, but modified to use more idiomatic features like `filter` with a helper function instead of `for`, `when`, and `println`.

This style of code returning a value is much more useful because the value it produces could be used in later code, where an imperative action like `println` would be much less reusable.

@Oscar Lopez's `make-matrix` function produces an initial list of possibilities, but we have to filter out the ones that are impossible, and leave only the ones that are possible. So write that down:

```
;; If there are no valid solutions, this will be an empty list,
;; if there's one, this will be a list of one element,
;; and if there are more, this will include all of them.
(filter valid-solution? (make-matrix 5))

;; Wish list:
;; valid-solution? : (Listof Boolean) -> Boolean
```

Now we just need to add a definition for `valid-solution?`

```
;; valid-solution? : (Listof Boolean) -> Boolean
;; Given a list containing booleans for whether Terry, Steve, Matt, Ben, and Carl did it,
;; this determines whether that combination is possible under the constraints in the problem.
(define (valid-solution? row)
  ; unpack each row into the corresponding variables
  (match-define (list t s m b c) row)
  ; don't reinvent the wheel, `oneof` is called `xor`
  (and (xor (not c) s)
       (xor (not m) (not c))
       (xor c (not t))
       (xor m s)
       (xor b (not t))))
```

And that's it. The full program including `make-matrix` is this:

```
#lang racket

;; make-matrix : Natural -> (Listof (Listof Boolean))
;; generate a matrix with possibilities
(define (make-matrix n)
  (for/list ([i (in-range n)])
    (build-list n (λ (j) (= i j)))))

;; valid-solution? : (Listof Boolean) -> Boolean
;; Given a list containing booleans for whether Terry, Steve, Matt, Ben, and Carl did it,
;; this determines whether that combination is possible under the constraints in the problem.
(define (valid-solution? row)
  ; unpack each row into the corresponding variables
  (match-define (list t s m b c) row)
  ; don't reinvent the wheel, `oneof` is called `xor`
  (and (xor (not c) s)
       (xor (not m) (not c))
       (xor c (not t))
       (xor m s)
       (xor b (not t))))

;; If there are no valid solutions, this will be an empty list,
;; if there's one, this will be a list of one element,
;; and if there are more, this will include all of them.
(filter valid-solution? (make-matrix 5))
```

Comment: Great functional solution.