# Functional variant of 'oneof' function in Racket

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket, xor

I have written following function to find if one and only one of 5 variables is true:

```
(define (oneof v w x y z)
  (or (and v (not w) (not x) (not y)  (not z))
      (and w (not v) (not x) (not y)  (not z))
      (and x (not v) (not w) (not y)  (not z))
      (and y (not v) (not w) (not x)  (not z))
      (and z (not v) (not w) (not x)  (not y))  ))
```

(xor takes only 2 arguments)

However, it is very imperative and not functional. Moreover, I want to write a function (oneof N) which will be generic rather than specific for 5 variables. How can this be done? Thanks.

Edit: As pointed out in the comments, the code is 'repetitive' and not 'imperative', though the need for its improvement remains.

Comment: For what it’s worth, nothing about the code you posted is terribly *imperative* (there are no side-effects, and everything is referentially transparent), it’s just very *repetitive*.

Comment: I wanted to have a loop rather than repetition. Also to make it more generic rather than for 5 variables only.

Comment: Yes, I agree that there are improvements over the code you posted—unnecessarily repetitive code is also to be avoided—but I was just pointing out that your observation that your code was imperative isn’t really accurate. *Imperative* is not a synonym for *bad*, as much as functional programmers might sometimes lead you to believe. ;)

Comment: I have added this observation in the Edit of my question above.

Answer (score 5):

Your final note is accurate: it sounds like `xor` is the right function but this, but it only takes two arguments. It would likely be better if `xor` took any number of arguments, but given that it doesn’t, we can implement it ourselves.

Perhaps the most naïve way would just to be to count the number of truthy values and check if that number is precisely 1. We can do this with `count` or `for/sum`, depending on your preference:

```
; using count
(define (xor . args)
  (= 1 (count identity args)))

; using for/sum
(define (xor . args)
  (= 1 (for/sum ([x (in-list args)])
         (if x 1 0))))
```

Both of these work, but they don’t preserve a useful property of Racket’s `xor`, which returns the single truthy element upon success rather than always returning a boolean. To do this, we could use a fold, using `foldl`, `foldr`, or `for/fold`. However, given that we want to ideally exit as soon as possible, using the `#:final` option of `for/fold` is pretty convenient:

```
(define (xor . args)
  (for/fold ([found #f])
            ([arg (in-list args)])
            #:final (and found arg)
    (if (and found arg) #f
        (or found arg))))
```

---

However, this is actually still not really *optimal*. The two-argument version of `xor` is a function, not a macro like `and` and `or`, because it cannot be lazy in either of its arguments. However, a many-argument `xor` actually can be. In order to add this short-circuiting behavior, we can write `xor` as a macro:

```
(define-syntax xor
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_) #f]
    [(_ x) x]
    [(_ x rest ...)
     (let ([v x])
       (if v
           (and (nor rest ...) v)
           (xor rest ...)))]))
```

In general, this works just like the function versions of `xor`:

```
> (xor #f #f #f #f #f)
#f
> (xor #f #f 1 #f #f)
1
> (xor #f #f 1 2 #f)
#f
```

However, like `and` and `or`, it sometimes “short-circuits”, not evaluating expressions if their results will not mater:

```
> (xor #f #f #f #f (begin (displayln "hello!") #f))
hello!
#f
> (xor #f #f 1 #f (begin (displayln "hello!") #f))
hello!
1
> (xor #f #f 1 2 (begin (displayln "hello!") #f))
#f
```

(Note that `hello!` is never printed in the last example.)

Is this a good idea, is it a bad idea…? I don’t really know. It does seem unlikely that this behavior will ever be super useful, and it adds a lot of complexity. It also prevents `xor` from being used higher-order, but you could get around that with `syntax-id-rules` and expanding to the procedure version when `xor` is used in an expression position. Still, it’s potentially interesting, and it makes its behavior more consistent with `and` and `or`, so I figured I’d include it for completeness.

Comment: xor was pointed out to me by @ÓscarLópez  in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38816383/solving-a-puzzle-in-racket

Answer (score 3):

You can literally *count* how many `true` values you have in a list of arbitrary length, if that number is `1` then we're good (remember that in Scheme any non-`false` value is considered `true`). Also notice how to create a procedure with a variable number of arguments, using the dot notation:

```
(define (oneof . vars)
  (= 1
     (count (lambda (v) (not (false? v)))
            vars)))
```

For example:

```
(oneof #f #f #f #f #t)
=> #t
(oneof #f #f #f #f #f)
=> #f
(oneof #t #t #t #t #t)
=> #f
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution, more concise, is the following:

```
(define (oneof . vars)
  (= 1 (count identity vars)))
```

Comment: @rnso The `identity` function is just an extremely simple function that always returns its argument. In this case, it’s being used as a predicate of sorts for `count`, which counts all arguments that result in a “truthy” result when the predicate is applied to them. In Scheme, all non-`#f` values are considered truthy, so `(count identity lst)` just counts how many elements of `lst` are non-`#f`.

Comment: Effectively it is (count (lambda (x) x) vars).