# define scheme macro for xor

Tags: macros, scheme, lisp, mit-scheme

Notice the following macro is working.

```
(define-syntax xor
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((xor a1 a2)
     (if a1
       (false? a2)
       (true? a2)))
    ((xor a1 a2 a3 ...)
     (let ((a (xor a1 a2)))
       (xor a a3 ...)))))
```

However it seems if I leave out the `a3` in the parameter list of the general case, it won't work properly.

```
(define-syntax xor
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((xor a1 a2)
     (if a1
       (false? a2)
       (true? a2)))
    ((xor a1 a2 ...)
     (let ((a (xor a1 a2)))
       (xor a ...)))))
```

Thus I am wondering what is going on exactly to the ellipsis in the second case.

**Q1.** Does that mean the each parameter list excluding the ellipsis should be unique for it to run properly?

For example given input `(xor #t #t #t)`, the first will produce `#t`, whereas the second will produce `#f`.

The interpreter I am using is `mit-scheme`.

**Q2.** And is it possible to make it short circuiting?

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Functional variant of 'oneof' function in Racket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38820738/functional-variant-of-oneof-function-in-racket)

Comment: Does it make sense to do this as a macro at all?  The 2-ary expansion has to evaluate the second argument regardless of the first, so how does it differ from a function `(lambda (a b) (if a (not b) b))`?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor You are correct. It will be better to define it as a function if there is no short circuiting. Here I just want to try it out as a macro, and try to resolve the ellipsis problem see **Q1**. And according to Sylwester looks like there exists a way to make it a short circuit. Then macro will be more beneficial than a function in that case.

Comment: @Lingxiao Short-circuiting doesn't make sense with XOR.  Consider **(xor v0 ... vn)**:  whatever the value of **(xor v0 ... vn-1)** is, you still need the value of **vn** to know what the final result is.  Short-circuiting with, for instance, **(and v0 ... vn)** only works because you know you know that if **(and v0 ... vn-1)** is *false*, then you don't need to know the value of **vn**, and you can skip computing it.

Answer (score 2):

The ellipses tells you something about the second symbol. `a2 ...` can be zero or more elements and you need to use `a2` in what is being repeated for it to work. In your second macro the result with `a2` is missing ellipsis for the recurring elements and you have `ellipsis` after `a` which isn't a part of the match pattern and also does not have ellipsis. Both of these facts make the macro invalid.

The first macro is correct since you have one term that matches two elements. Your second term also matches two terms, but since the first pattern that matches is run you are sure you have more than two arguments for your second pattern since it matched two with `a3 ...` being at least one element.

I'm not sure what the `true?` is for. A slight simplification:

```scm
(define-syntax xor
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((xor a1 a2)
     (if a1 (not a2) a2))
    ((xor a1 a2 a3 ...)
     (xor (xor a1 a2) a3 ...))))

(xor 1 2 3 4 5)  ; ==> 5  (odd number of true values)
(xor 1 2 3 4)    ; ==> #f (even number of true values)
(xor 1 2 3 4 #f) ; ==> #f (even number of true values)
(xor 1 #f #f #f) ; ==> #t (odd number of true values)
```

Now this will calculate the odd parity of the argument expressions. It can not be short circuited since it flip flops. `(xor #t #t #f #f #t) ; ==> #t` since it has an odd number of true arguments. That's about what it does and while it's daisy chaining `xor` logic it doesn't really have the only one true logic left. Since you can never short circuit it you might as well use a procedure that does the exact same thing:

```scm
(define (xor . args)
  (= (remainder (count values args) 2) 1))

(xor 1 2 3 4 5)  ; ==> #t (odd number of true values)
(xor 1 2 3 4)    ; ==> #f (even number of true values)
(xor 1 2 3 4 #f) ; ==> #f (even number of true values)
(xor 1 #f #f #f) ; ==> #t (odd number of true values)
```

Count can be found in the [SRFI-1 list library](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#count).

There is another interpretation of `xor` and that is the first one I though about when I read this question since it's the only case where short circuit works. It is one that is true iff one expression is true, otherwise the result is false. Here, when encountering the second false value you can short circuit to `#f` without evaluating the rest of the arguments.

```scm
(define-syntax xor
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_) #f)
    ((_ a) a)
    ((_ a b ...)
     (if a
         (not (or b ...))
         (xor b ...)))))

(xor 1 2 3 4 5)  ; ==> #f (more than one true value)
(xor 1 2 3 4)    ; ==> #f (more than one true value)
(xor 1 2 3 4 #f) ; ==> #f (more than one true value)
(xor 1 #f #f #f) ; ==> #t (only one true value)

;; Slightly more complex version where 
;; the result is always the one true value or #f
(define-syntax xor
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_) #f)
    ((_ a) a)
    ((_ a b ...)
     (let ((tmp a))
       (if tmp 
           (and (not (or b ...)) tmp)
           (xor b ...))))))

(xor 1 2 3 4 5)  ; ==> #f
(xor 1 2 3 4)    ; ==> #f
(xor 1 2 3 4 #f) ; ==> #f
(xor 1 #f #f #f) ; ==> 1 (the actual true value, consistent)
```

Most algorithms won't have any speed penalties from using a procedure, but I guess there might be a few situations where this macro might be in handy as a macro. The procedure version of the one that doesn't keep the value is very similar to the procedure version of the other one:

```scm
(define (xor . args)
  (= (count values args) 1))
```

Comment: Hi, I am still a little confused about how the short circuiting works. Consider `(xor #t #f #t #t)` for example, this should really evaluate to `#t`, but due to the short circuiting behavior, it will evaluate to `#f`. So shouldn't this be incorrect?

Comment: Short-circuiting doesn't make sense with XOR.  Consider **(xor v0 ... vn)**:  whatever the value of **(xor v0 ... vn-1)** is, you still need the value of **vn** to know what the final result is.  Short-circuiting with, for instance, **(and v0 ... vn)** only works because you know you know that if **(and v0 ... vn-1)** is *false*, then you don't need to know the value of **vn**, and you can skip computing it.

Comment: *"If only one of the expressions are a true value that true value is the result while when two of the arguments are true the rest are not evaluated and it short circuits to #f."*  That's not XOR though.  For instance, **(xor #t #t #t) = (xor (xor #t #t) #t) = (xor #f #t) = #t**.  So you can't stop after seeing two trues and conclude that the whole expression is false.  Remember that XOR is essentially counting whether the number of set bits is odd or even (a parity bit).  To do that, you need to evaluate all the arguments.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor The definition of `xor` has [two possible interpretations](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/93713/how-is-an-xor-with-more-than-2-inputs-supposed-to-work). One that calculates odd parity and one that is true when only one of the input is true and all of the rest is false. It's the latter I have made. Short circuiting does work in this case since if you have a second true value the rest of the expressions can be anything and the result is still false.

Comment: I am not a fan of calling the "exactly one" interpretation "exclusive or", but I do recognize that it does exist out there. However OP's original macro is clearly using the parity bit interpretation based on the expansion that compares the first two values and then continues to compare the remaining values.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to use fanciful `define-syntax` but this might offer some help.

If anyone can explain why `xor` should be defined as syntax instead of a simple procedure, I'd like to know ^_^

```
(define (xor a b . xs)
  (cond [(and a b)   #f]
        [(empty? xs) (or a b)]
        [else        (apply xor (or a b) (car xs) (cdr xs))]))

(xor #t #f)             ; => #t
(xor #t #t)             ; => #f
(xor #t #f #f)          ; => #t
(xor #t #f #f #t)       ; => #f
(xor #f #f #f #f #f #t) ; => #t
```