# Can anyone help me with this simple boolean scheme code?

Tags: scheme, racket

I need to define XOR3 that takes boolean inputs a b and c that will return true when exactly one input is true and false otherwise. Been stuck on this forever!

So far, I have
(define XOR3 
   (lambda (a b c) but idk what to put after because I cannot figure out how to get true when only one value is true. I am only supposed to use "or" "and" and "not". Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break it down into smaller problems.

What does it mean that exacly one of `a`, `b`, `c` is true?
It means that only `a` is true, OR only `b` is true, OR only `c` is true.
So your function will have the structure

```
(define (xor3 a b c)
    (or only-a
        only-b
        only-c))
```

Next step: what does it mean that only `a` is true?
It means that `a` is true, AND `b` isn't true, AND `c` isn't true.
That is,

```
(and a (not b) (not c))
```

so you can plug that into the function.

Similarly for `b` and `c`.

Comment: May be worth mentioning that this is the [DNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form).

Answer (score 2):

Just start with the simplest case and keep narrowing it down

```
(define (xor3 a b c)
  (cond [(and a b) #f]           ; explanation step 1
        [(false? c) (or a b)]    ; explanation step 2
        [else (not (or a b))]))  ; explanation step 3

(xor3 #t #t #t) ; => #f
(xor3 #t #t #f) ; => #f
(xor3 #t #f #t) ; => #f
(xor3 #t #f #f) ; => #t
(xor3 #f #t #t) ; => #f
(xor3 #f #t #f) ; => #t
(xor3 #f #f #t) ; => #t
(xor3 #f #f #f) ; => #f
```

Here's the explanation of how my brain processed this:

1. if `a` and `b` are both`#t`, it doesn't matter what `c` is, return `#f`
2. now we only know that `a` and `b` aren't *both* true, so if `c` *is* `#f` we can just return `(or a b)`
3. otherwise `c` is `#t` which means neither `a` or `b` can be true – instead of `(not (or a b))` you can think of this as `(and (not a) (not b))` if you'd like.

Remember to always work with your truth table like I did above so that you can verify the validity of your procedure for all possible assignments of `a`, `b`, and `c`

---

Of course your next logical step is to create a generic procedure which accepts any number of arguments; not just 3

```
(define (xor a b . xs)
  (cond [(and a b)   #f]
        [(empty? xs) (or a b)]
        [else        (apply xor (or a b) (car xs) (cdr xs))]))
```

Don't forget to check the truth table

```
(xor #t #t #t #t) ; => #f
(xor #t #t #t #f) ; => #f
(xor #t #t #f #t) ; => #f
(xor #t #t #f #f) ; => #f
(xor #t #f #t #t) ; => #f
(xor #t #f #t #f) ; => #f
(xor #t #f #f #t) ; => #f
(xor #t #f #f #f) ; => #t
(xor #f #t #t #t) ; => #f
(xor #f #t #t #f) ; => #f
(xor #f #t #f #t) ; => #f
(xor #f #t #f #f) ; => #t
(xor #f #f #t #t) ; => #f
(xor #f #f #t #f) ; => #t
(xor #f #f #f #t) ; => #t
(xor #f #f #f #f) ; => #f
```

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward solution would be to use `or` with `and` and `not` since your procedure should be true when `a` is true and the rest is false OR `b` is true and the rest is false OR `c` is true and the rest is false.

```
(define (xor3 a b c) 
  (or (and a (not b) (not c)) 
      (and b (not a) (not c)) 
      (and c (not a) (not b))))
```

Answer (score 0):

One can also put these items in a list and use count function:

```
(define (f a b c)
  (if (= 1
         (count
          (lambda(x) x)
          (list a b c)))
      #t #f ))
```

Or, simplified version suggested by @AlexKnauth in comments below:

```
(define (f a b c)
  (= 1
     (count
       (lambda(x) x)
       (list a b c) )))
```

Testing:

```
(f #t #f #f)
(f #t #t #f)
```

Output:

```
#t
#f
```

This function is highly flexible and can be used for testing any number of items for any number of true values.

Also see: [Functional variant of 'oneof' function in Racket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38820738/functional-variant-of-oneof-function-in-racket)

Comment: You don't need the `(if ... #t #f)` around it, you can just use `(= 1 (count ...))`

Answer (score -3):

```
bool a=true, b=false, c=false;

Label1.Text = ((a == true && b == false && c == false) 
            || (a == false && b == true && c == false) 
            || (a == false && b == false && c == true) ? true : false).ToString();
```

Comment: The OP is asking for a solution in Scheme, not in Java!

Comment: Comparisons with booleans are pointless. For instance, `a == true` is equivalent to `a` and `a == false` is equivalent to `!a`. Boolean results from the ternary operators are also pointless; `p ? true : false` is the same as `p` and `p ? false : true` is `!p`.